# ntdef.h missing from SDK and WDK

Tags: visual-studio, wdk, kmdf

I am trying to build a `KMDF Driver` project, but when including `ntddk.h` and `wdf.h`, I get errors along the lines of:

```
variable "_IRQL_requires_same_" is not a type name
variable "ULONG" is not a type name
variable "NTSYSAPI" is not a type name
```

There seems to be many definitions I'm missing, despite [a Microsoft tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/gettingstarted/writing-a-very-small-kmdf--driver) specifying only these two imports.

I am using Visual Studio 2022, WDK 10.0.22621.1 (verified by checking the `Add or remove a program` windows menu), Windows 11 SDK 10.0.22621.0 (verified by checking the VS installer), and the Driver Kit VS extension seems to be installed properly (I can create driver projects).

Is there anything obvious I'm missing? Anything I should try?